# Number of disk block reads in nested-loop join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, nested-loops

I'm trying to understand how to calculate the number of disk blocks that is being read when a nested-loop join is being performed.

In my book it says that the number of I/Os made in a nested-loop join is:

```
O + ⌈O/(b−2)⌉ * I
```

where O is the number of blocks in the outer loop and I is the number of blocks in the inner loop.

Is this the same as calculating the number of blocks that needs to be read from disk when performing a nested-loop join?

Comment: Is your question a theoretical one, or is it about the performance of an actual server implementation? Actual implementations have complex caching and block-allocation schemes whose purpose is to defeat the theoretical minimums whenever possible, so you'll have a lot of trouble matching your calculations to actual performance.

Answer (score 0):

Your book is probably wrong.  The number of *attempted* reads will be given by a formula like that.  I would expect the formula to be O*I -- and it is not clear what `b` is in the formula.

However, databases have something called a page cache.  So, the pages are generally stored in memory and the number of *actual* reads would be more like O + I.  Once the pages are in memory, they do not need another I/O.

Of course, not all tables fit into memory.  In that case the number of reads is much higher and depends on how the cache works.

If the conclusion of the discussion is to avoid nested loop joins, then the book is correct.